# How do I check if a word falls in one or the other array?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, if-statement

I'm trying to read through a text file word by word and then compare that word to a set of categorized arrays (joy, sadness, anger etc.) and if it is in that array, add the identifier for that array (a unique number assigned to them) to an empty list.

This is what I have:

```
anger = ['abandoned', 'abandonment', 'abhor', 'abhorrent', 'abolish',....]
joy = ['absolution', 'abundance', .....]
sadness = ['abandoned', ....]
trust = ['example word']

# Python program to read  
# file word by word 
DNA = []
# opening the text file 
with open('ch1.txt','r', encoding="utf8") as file: 
   
    # reading each line     
    for line in file: 
   
        # reading each word         
        for word in line.split(): 
             if word in joy:
               DNA.append('6');
    
    # reading each line     
    for line in file: 
   
        # reading each word         
        for word in line.split():            
             if word in anger:
                DNA.append('2');
                
     # reading each line     
    for line in file: 
   
        # reading each word         
        for word in line.split():      
             if word in fear:
                DNA.append('5');
           
      # reading each line     
    for line in file: 
   
        # reading each word         
        for word in line.split():        
             if word in sadness:
                DNA.append('7');
     
        
     # reading each line     
    for line in file: 
   
        # reading each word         
         for word in line.split():      
             if word in trust:
                DNA.append('9');
               
       # reading each line     
    for line in file: 
   
        # reading each word         
        for word in line.split(): 
             if word in surprise:
               DNA.append('8');
             
       # reading each line     
    for line in file: 
   
        # reading each word         
        for word in line.split():       
             if word in disgust:
               DNA.append('4');

 
print("Emotional DNA: " ,DNA)
```

What I want the code to do is something like this:

```
if word is in anger:
   add anger to the list;

or if word is in sadness:
   add sadness to the list;
```

The word can also appear in multiple categories and in that case both the category identifiers should be appended to the list.

This is the output I expect:

```
2, 2, 2, 4, 6, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4,8, 4, 5
```

In summary, all I want is to match the word being read in to see if it falls in one (or multiple) categories, and then add that category's identifier to the empty list. This is to map the progression of these emotion categories in the text file, one by one.

What is happening with the current code is that it is just reading through the first if statement and giving me this:

```
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6
```

When I tried replacing the if statements after the first one with elif, only the first two statements were read and the others were ignored. I don't know how to make this if-else-if ladder work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: instead of lists for "emotions" use sets and your program will run much faster

Comment: @woblob I'm not quite sure how that is done. I've been told dictionaries work well too but it seems a little hard for me to understand. Would the checking process be the same (if word in anger)?

Comment: yes, then you can skip one hidden for loop which is "element in list", for sets and dictionaries/hashtables this lookup is O(1) or instantaneous

Comment: If you use `{"word1", "word2"}` instead of `["word1", "word2"]`, the rest of the code can be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only read through the lines and words once. Then test the words against each list inside that loop.

```
for line in file:
    for word in line.split():
        if word in joy:
            DNA.append('6')
        if word in anger:
            DNA.append('2')
        if word in fear:
            DNA.append('5')
        # and so on
```

You're only getting one set of numbers because after you've read through the file, there's nothing left for the next `for line in file` loop to read. You could rewind with `file.seek(0)` first, but then you'll get all the `6`, then all the `2`, etc. You won't know what order they actually occurred in the file.

BTW, if the word lists are large, you should use sets rather than lists.

Comment: Using `elif`, a word that falls in multiple categories will only result in one category rather than all of them. So they should be individual `if` statements

Comment: If a word is in multiple categories, it will be impossible to correlate the result with the words, unless they use nested lists.

Comment: Doesn't this just check the first or the first two categories and ignore the rest if one of them checks True?

Comment: I just noticed that the question specifically says that a word can be in multiple categories. So I changed from elif to if

Comment: But how will you know which DNA elements correspond to which words in the input? Or you don't care?

Comment: We don't really care about that. The point is just to indicate where these emotions occur, regardless of the word associated with them. Words can fall in multiple categories because for the word 'abandoned', we can interpret that as either 'sadness', 'anger' and so both of them should be appended to the list.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that you are looping through the file several times, only looking for matches with one particular list each time.

You can put all the `if` statements into one for loop:

```py
with open('ch1.txt','r', encoding="utf8") as file: 
   
    # reading each line     
    for line in file: 
   
        # reading each word         
        for word in line.split(): 
             if word in joy:
               DNA.append('6');

             if word in anger:
                DNA.append('2');

             if word in fear:
                DNA.append('5');

             if word in sadness:
                DNA.append('7');
```

This way the letters will be added word by word, rather than category by category.

Comment: I tried running this but the program still outputs only the first two if statements. I verified this by forcefully adding a word from the sadness array but it did not show up.

Comment: @AmanBhargava This should work (my answer is the same now). Does the text have punctuation? `line.split()` won't remove that, you'll need to do that first.

Comment: @Barmar Is there any reason why the punctuation interferes with this? I did not remember to clear the text, yes, but I didn't know it would be a problem.

Comment: If you don't remove the punctuation, `word` will be something like `"abhor,"`. That's not in any of the word lists, because they only contain words without punctuation.

Comment: Also, you can't have multi-word phrases like `"example word"` in your category lists. You're splitting the input into single words, so they'll never match a phrase like that.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using a NLP library instead of this ad hoc mechanism.

Comment: @Barmar That was just there to illustrate what the list could contain! This code seems correct but for whatever reason, even by forcing a term from the latter arrays, it is not showing up in the output! [I've uploaded the files here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KW36EITM_uKXZYBkuKmX4dgoc_p_W5Zr?usp=sharing), if is possible for you to go through them when you have a chance? I think NLP would be worth learning though, this is a headache!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221997/discussion-between-aman-bhargava-and-barmar).